# What should be done when moderators go crazy and/or power hungry?

Tags: discussion

BH

Just wondering what the proper procedure should be taken if it, theoretically, becomes clear that a particular moderator continues to break policy rules and/or is just plain power hungry and starts deleting valid questions and comments without any discussion etc., I haven't found anything in the policies that discuss this

Comment: תשובה תפילה וצדקה מעבירין את רע הגזרה

Comment: This is a growing concern around here, I have had many on topic comments deleted by a certain zealous moderator. It seems that there have been 2 election periods for moderators since Mi Yodeya was formed. Once in 2012 and once in 2017. This leaves power concentrated in the hands of a few users elected during periods of low participation, many years ago.

Answer (score 15):

There are several things you could do (in order of preference, in my opinion) including but not limited to:

- Create a Meta post with specific details about specific posts that were deleted, and why you think they shouldn't have been, so that the community at large can review them.
- Create a flag with the reason "in need of moderator intervention" and explain your complaint, so that other moderators can look into it and see if their colleague is in fact abusing power.
- Use the "contact" feature at the bottom of the page to formally complain to the Stack Exchange management team. Stack Exchange has in the past removed moderators for egregious abuse of power.